# Inconsistent authorization warning and error while using az storage entity query

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage, azure-cli, azure-storage-account, azure-rbac

When I issue the following command:

`az storage entity query --account-name acc1 --table-name table1`

I successfully get my query result with the following *warning*:

```
There are no credentials provided in your command and environment, we will query for account key for your storage account.
It is recommended to provide --connection-string, --account-key or --sas-token in your command as credentials.

You also can add `--auth-mode login` in your command to use Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) for authorization if your login account is assigned required RBAC roles.
For more information about RBAC roles in storage, visit https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad-rbac-cli.

In addition, setting the corresponding environment variables can avoid inputting credentials in your command. Please use --help to get more information about environment variable usage.
```

To avoid above warning, I add `--auth-mode login` to the command:

`az storage entity query --account-name acc1 --table-name table1 --auth-mode login`

Then I get this error:

```
You do not have the required permissions needed to perform this operation.
Depending on your operation, you may need to be assigned one of the following roles:
    "Storage Blob Data Owner"
    "Storage Blob Data Contributor"
    "Storage Blob Data Reader"
    "Storage Queue Data Contributor"
    "Storage Queue Data Reader"
    "Storage Table Data Contributor"
    "Storage Table Data Reader"

If you want to use the old authentication method and allow querying for the right account key, please use the "--auth-mode" parameter and "key" value.
```

My account is able to get the query result without `--auth-mode login` switch. Why it fails authorization with the switch?

Answer (score 1):

When you don't specify the authentication type, it will try yo get the access key of the storage account:
This requires `Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/listkeys/action` permission. If you have contributor role oier the storage account, you have the required permission.

`--auth-mode login` means it will use AAD auth to connect to the storage. You can use of the built-in roles to access the storage (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/tables/authorize-access-azure-active-directory)):

- Storage Table Data Contributor
- Storage Table Data Reader

When using AAD Auth, you could also disable access key authentication.

There is an good article related to RBAC management and data plane model:
[Assign an Azure role for access to blob data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/assign-azure-role-data-access?tabs=portal#assign-an-azure-role).